# List to be sorted via lambda

Tags: python, sorting

```
LIST = ['aaa', 'aa', 'ba', 'b', 'AA', 'zz', 'c']

print (sorted(LIST, key=lambda s: s.casefold())) 

print (sorted(LIST, key=lambda s: len(s)))
```

combine both into one Lambda - expected result:

```
['b', 'c', 'aa', 'AA', 'ba',  'zz', 'aaa']
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `key` parameter you can sort first by `len`, then if those are equal it will fall back to sort by `str.casefold` semantics.

```
>>> sorted(LIST, key=lambda s: (len(s), s.casefold()))
['b', 'c', 'aa', 'AA', 'ba', 'zz', 'aaa']
```